# How to work with [Authorize] attribute in .NET

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am newbie to .NET, while reading about the filters concept, I came across the attribute `[Authorize]`. Whenever we apply this attribute on a controller or action method, we can't even access the the controller.

Most of the tutorials or documents are providing this information. But I'm unable to identify that how this `[Authorize]` attribute knows that the user is authorized or not? From where does it get the information whether a user is authorized or not?

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: The `HttpContext` of an ASP.NET Core application has a [`User` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.user?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which contains information about the current user - including the fact whether or not he's authorized (or not).

Comment: Then, why dont we use a completely httpcontext ? Does authorize uses httpcontext in any class or method ?

Comment: The `[Authorize]` attribute inspects the currently logged in user in the `HttpContext`, and if the user isn't authorized, it will not allow the method to be executed.

Comment: @marc_s so you mean to say like httpcontext will have the requested user details ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the `[Authorize]` attribute in ASP.NET Core doesn't directly call a specific class or method to validate the user. Put this attribute means to let the asp.net core authentication or authorization middleware to check if a user is authorized or not.

Authentication Middleware is used to check the user is authenticated by request's cookie or auth tokens, it will add the user's information into the claims.

Then Authorization Middleware, will check the claims according to the `[Authorize]` attribute's property like role or policy to decide if user could access the controller or not.

Comment: Means like finally this attribute from middleware checks in claims for a user ?

Comment: Yes, the middleware will call some method to check the claims.

Comment: Okay. Can we trace out that which method it is calling ?

Comment: The OnAuthorizationAsync method in the AuthorizeFilter class.  Details, you could check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.authorization.authorizefilter?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about ASP .NET Web APIs or Web Applications (ex. Blazor, etc.), there is this authorization process in which the API user (client)  need to get a key (token) from the server in order to prove that it has access to the API, and using the [Authorize] attribute we make sure that the user calling an endpoint has a valid token and therefore is logged in to our service.

For further info, you can look up JWT token in .NET.

Comment: Which class or method does authorize attribute is going to call to make sure the user is valid or not ?

Comment: Authorization is handled automatically using Identity Roles and Policy's. Unless you need a custom authorization procedure. In that case you can look into AuthorizationHandler s and AuthorizationService

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).